# Firebase + DialogFlow - Realtime database- Cloud function return query result only after second request

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm writing a simple Google Action which will read the Firebase Realtime Database, and return result in the response. My problem is, the query result is being passed back in response to DialogFlow only after at least 2 attempts.
Below the screenshots showing the end result in the Simulator
[First query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4VGI.png)
The first line of the response is returned from the Cloud Function, and contains values passed with the "Context". There is no second line in this response.

below is the screen showing the result after sending exactly the same request second time.
[Second query screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfO5i.png)
First line is the same as previously, but this time I also get the second line which contains the query result data.

It looks like my code is "working" (I get the correct data from the database), but for some reason it only works if I trigger it at least 2 times in quick succession.

Below is the code snipped which handle this request:

```
  function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
   let conv = agent.conv();  
   let outCommandContext = agent.getContext('outcommand');
   let outCharacterContext = agent.getContext('outcharacter');
   let character = outCharacterContext.parameters.character;
   let command = outCommandContext.parameters.command;
   agent.add('<prosody rate="140%" pitch="0.4">' + character +' '+ command +'</prosody>');  
   var movesRef = admin.database().ref('characters/'+character.toLowerCase()+'/moves/'); 

   movesRef.limitToFirst(1).orderByChild("notation")
   .equalTo(command.toString()).on("child_added",function(snapshot){      
   agent.add(`record number is ` + snapshot.key);  
 }); 

}
```

I've tried using once() instead of on() (as it would make more sense in my case... i don't need to listen to changes on the database, i just want to retrieve data once)- but, I couldn't get it to work.

Can you guys help me out understanding **why** my query returns result only after the second trigger?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using a callback method to get the data from database so there is no guaranty that it will be called before your function is returned. to solve the issue, you need to use a Promise and return that Promise in your function so the last few lines of your function will look like this

```
return movesRef.limitToFirst(1).orderByChild("notation")
             .equalTo(command.toString()).on("child_added").then(snapshot= > {      
                      agent.add(`record number is ` + snapshot.key);          
                       });
```

Comment: I think my issue is resolved, thanks to your answer. However, i had to use once() instead of on() - AND I think the problem was, I never used 'return' - I did try to use once() before, exactly the way you mentioned, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to always use promises when working with databases. Moreover, the first response that you see might be because of the failed function which timed out. If you see your console logs in firebase, you might see the errors. Also check your default response, if it has the text that `User said $name` or something similar, then that is what causes the issue in the first attempt.
If you still don't get it to work, try logging the returned data and post your logs here.